# Getting count of latest items from secondary view

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got a problem constructing a somewhat advanced query.

I have two views - **A** and **B** where **B** is the child of **A**.

This relationship is handled by

- **A** vw_StartDate.MapToID

  =
- **B** vw_TrackerFeaturesBasic.StartDateMapToID.

What I need to do is grab every parent **A** and a count of the *LATEST added* children **B**.

This is a query that gets the latest children **B** in a SSRS-report: (This does not use **A** at all!):

```
/****** Selecting the incomplete, applicable issues of the latest insert.  ******/
SELECT DISTINCT [TRK_Feature_LKID]
      ,[TrackerGroupDescription]
      ,[ApplicableToProject]
      ,[ReadyForWork]
      ,[DateStamp]
      
 FROM [vw_TRK_TrackerFeaturesBasic] as temp
 WHERE ApplicableToProject = 1 
 AND DateStamp = (SELECT MAX(DateStamp) from [vw_TRK_TrackerFeaturesBasic] WHERE [TRK_StartDateID] = @WSCTrackerID AND StartDateMapToID = @HierarchyID AND [TRK_Feature_LKID] = temp.TRK_Feature_LKID )
  
  ORDER BY DateStamp DESC
```

I've tried a few different ways, but I can't figure out how to get the latest added children from the subquery (I've mainly used a subquery nestled in a COUNT / Case + SUM).

Since SQL Server doesn't really allow us to use aggregate functions in aggregate functions I'm not sure how to get the latest added item in a subquery as the subquery most likely has to be nested in a COUNT or something similar.

Below is a version I'm working on (doesn't work):

> Column 'vw_TRK_TrackerFeaturesBasic.StartDateMapToID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

```
SELECT   b.TRK_StartDateID
       ,(SELECT COUNT(b.TRK_Feature_LKID) FROM b )
FROM vw_TRK_StartDate as a
    LEFT JOIN vw_TRK_TrackerFeaturesBasic as b
    ON b.StartDateMapToID = a.MapToID AND b.DateStamp = (SELECT MAX(DateStamp) FROM [vw_TRK_TrackerFeaturesBasic] WHERE [TRK_StartDateID] = 47 AND [StartDateMapToID] = 13)
WHERE MapToId = 13

--(SELECT MAX(DateStamp) from [vw_TRK_TrackerFeaturesBasic] WHERE [TRK_StartDateID] = @WSCTrackerID AND StartDateMapToID = @HierarchyID AND [TRK_Feature_LKID] = temp.TRK_Feature_LKID 

GROUP BY b.TRK_StartDateID
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit hard to follow, because I don't see a relationship between your queries and this request:

> What I need to do is grab every parent A and a count of the LATEST
>   added children B.

Focusing on this statement, you can do this readily with window functions:

```
SELECT b.StartDateMapToID, COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT tfb.*,
             MAX(tfb.DateStamp) OVER (PARTITION BY tfb.StartDateMapToID) as max_DateStamp
      FROM vw_TRK_TrackerFeaturesBasic tfb
     ) tfb
GROUP BY b.StartDateMapToID;
```

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm simply not really sure how to formulate a good question about SQL. I tried copy-pasting your answer, but didn't get the expected results..

Basically what I need is a query that grabs every parent and a count of the applicable (ApplicableToProject) and incomplete(ReadyForWork) rows of the latest (MAX(DateStamp)) inserted child.

Every child has the above mentioned fields and each I need to get a count of the latest inserted child where above fields are Applicable = 1, ready = 0.

Comment: @geostocker . . . You should ask another question with appropriate sample data and desired results.